# Punch animation from Roblox tutorial is throwing errors

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to get a punch animation to work from a tutorial, but it never works when I press the designated Keybinding.

I have tried changing values from the tutorial from 1 to the animation length, past the animation length, and even random numbers. I also tried changing some wording to the script.

```
math.randomseed(tick())

local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local punchEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent", ReplicatedStorage)
punchEvent.Name = "PunchEvent"

local animation = (03910055905)

local function onPunchFired(plr)
    local char = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(plr.Name)
    local humanoid = char.Humanoid
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "http://roblox.com/asset/?id="..animations[math.random(1, #animations)]
    local animTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    animTrack:Play()
end


punchEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(onPunchFired)
```

I expect the script to run smooth and punch, but it shows this:

`20:46:29.496 - ServerScriptService.ExtremePunch:13: attempt to get length of global 'animations' (a nil value)`

This is all it says in the output for errors. I've double checked the replication, but it keeps failing. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is pointing at this line :

`animation.AnimationId = "http://roblox.com/asset/?id="..animations[math.random(1, #animations)]`

This is because in the scope of this script, there is no local variable or array named `animations`.

To fix your code, you just have to fix the number in the `animation.AnimationId` url. One problem you might have run into was that you had two variables named `animation` so it failed to construct the url properly for you.

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local punchEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent", ReplicatedStorage)
punchEvent.Name = "PunchEvent"

local function onPunchFired(plr)
    local char = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(plr.Name)
    local humanoid = char.Humanoid
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://3910055905"
    local animTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    animTrack:Play()
end

punchEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(onPunchFired)
```

If you're unsure if your asset id is correct, you can also check by putting it into the url for the Roblox Catalog : [https://www.roblox.com/catalog/YOUR_ASSET_ID_NUMBER](https://www.roblox.com/library/3910055905/Punch). If it redirects to your animation, you know you've got the right one.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

The `animations` list does not exist in the code that you showed us.  So, add your other punch animations to the `animations` list that I added and you should be good to go.  I didn't test it so if it's not working, HMU.

```lua
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local punchEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
punchEvent.Name = "PunchEvent"
punchEvent.Parent = replicatedStorage

local animations = [03910055905, ...]

local function onPunchFired(plr)
    local char = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(plr.Name)
    local humanoid = char.Humanoid
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://" .. tostring(animations[math.random(1, #animations)])

    local animTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    animTrack:Play()
end

punchEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(onPunchFired)
```